# C++ error "not all control paths return a value"

Tags: c++

I am trying to output the reverse of a string by calling a function. I think there is something wrong with my reverse function.
I keep getting the error "not all control paths return a value."

```
#include<iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;
int LengthofString(    char *); // declaring prototype for length of the string 
int ReverseD(char *);

int main()
{
    char string1[100];
    cout<<"Enter a string: ";
    cin>>string1;

    cout<<"Length of string is "<<LengthofString(string1)<<endl<<ReverseD(string1)<<endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

int LengthofString(   char *x)
{
    int index;
    for(index = 0; *x!='\0';x++,index++);

    return index;
}

int reverse(char* y)
{
  int ii, n;
  n = LengthofString(y); 
  for(ii=0; ii<n/2;ii++) {
    char temp;
    temp = y[ii];
    y[ii] = y[n - ii - 1];
    y[n - ii] = temp;
    return temp;
  }
}
```

Comment: @H2CO3, In `reverse`. As it is, if `n` is 0 (or 1, or a negative somehow), the for loop won't execute and it will run off the end of the function.

Comment: @chris Oh, yes, sure.

Comment: (Y U people fail to compile with `-Wall`???)

Answer (score 3):

In the `reverse` function, you `return` inside the `for` loop, which might not be executed if the conditions are met.  Try moving the return statement outside of the loop.

Your return variable is also declared in the scope of the loop so you'll need to change that too, but this will at least fix your original error.

Comment: @SamIam What? `for(ii=0; ii<n/2;ii++) { ... return temp; }`

Comment: @SamIam (Time to let your high horse have a bit of rest. And remove your downvote, it's unjust.)

Comment: @H2CO3  How is it that `return index` is inside the for-loop when there's a semicolon between the end of the for loop and `return`?

Comment: @SamIam Read the quotation. We are talking about a different loop.

Answer (score 2):

Your `reverse` function is very wrong: how could it return `int` when you expect it to reverse a string? There are several ways to fix it:

- Remove the `return`, and make the function `void`. Call it before printing, and then output the original.
- Make it return `char*`, and return `y`. Move `return` statement out of the loop.
- Do not reverse in place: make a copy of the string, and reverse it; don't forget to allocate space for null terminator, and delete the copy of the string once you are done.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass an empty string or a string with length 1, the `return` statement in the following `for` loop will not get executed,

```
for(ii=0; ii<n/2;ii++) {
     char temp;
     temp = y[ii];
     y[ii] = y[n - ii - 1];
     y[n - ii] = temp;
     return temp;
}
```

Comment: Not only empty string, a string with length 1 will not enter the loop too.

Answer (score 0):

```
int reverse(char* y)
{
  int ii, n;
  n = LengthofString(y); 
  for(ii=0; ii<n/2;ii++) {
    char temp;
    temp = y[ii];
    y[ii] = y[n - ii - 1];
    y[n - ii] = temp;
    return temp;
  }
//because here you done have a return call; return something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the already existing excellent answers, let me show you how to reverse a string **the C++ way:**

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string s;
    std::cin >> s;
    std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:** Having to use your own function is not an excuse for writing C code in C++...

```
std::string reverseString(const std::string &input)
{
    std::string res;
    for (std::string::const_reverse_iterator it = input.rbegin(); it != input.rend(); it++)
        res += *it;

    return res;
}
```

Comment: I have to use my own function.

Comment: @BaidNation See update - your code is still C and not C++.